# Aggregate values ignore groupby while select

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker

I have table:

| sku | warehouse | sellable_units | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 | x |
| B | 2 | 30 | x |
| C | 1 | 10 | y |

i can not ignore group_by warehouse because i am using looker.the looker genrated query is:

```
select warehouse,sum(sellable_units) from table group by 1 where location="x".
```

but i do not want to split sellable_units on warehouse .

I want to select:

| warehouse | sellable_units |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 |
| 2 | 40 |

Comment: how to get 40? 30 + 10? what's the result for your query?

Comment: yes it is 30+10 my current query returns 1 10,2 30

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
SELECT a.warehouse, b.sellable_units
FROM
    tbl a
    join
    (SELECT SUM(sellable_units) as sellable_units FROM tbl) as b
```

Comment: hi as i mention i am using looker i can not do changes in from or can not do join.i can only change in select

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing window functions:

```
select 
  warehouse,
  sum(sellable_units) over (partition by location) as sellable_units 
from sample_data
  where location = "x"
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use "cancel_grouping_fields" at the explore level to specify which fields should be excluded from the GROUP BY.

```
explore: explore_name {
  cancel_grouping_fields: [view_name. warehouse]
}
```

Comment: i think that will cancel group by for whole explore is it possible for cancel group by on measure?

Comment: Yes, you are right. it will cancel the group by from the whole explore. When you have a measure, Looker always generates SQL query with group by based on existing dimension. So, maybe one possible option would be creating a dimension from the sellable_units measure. Currently, you have a defined measure, namely sellable_units with type: sum. You can create a dimension referring to this measure with type: number and use this dimension instead of measure to prevent group by.